# Can I use jQuery to toggle 'reversed' on an ordered list?

Tags: jquery

I'm working with ten `<section>`'s.

All sections have a header `<h1>` followed by an ordered list `<ol>`.

Only **two** sections have a `<span>sort</span>` inside their header.

I wish to use those *sort-span's* to toggle (reverse) the order of only those two lists.

---

Section with a list appearing in ascending alphabetical order:

```
<section>
    <h1>artists <span>sort</span></h1>
    <ol>
        <li>Hockney, David</li>
        <li>Matisse, Henri</li>
        <li>Picasso, Pablo</li>
    </ol>
</section>
```

Artists

- Hockney, David
- Matisse, Henri
- Picasso, Pablo

---

Section with a 'reversed' list appearing in descending alphabetical order:

Note: I have simply added "reversed" to the `<ol>` ordered list.

```
<section>
    <h1>artists <span>sort</span></h1>
    <ol reversed>
        <li>03. Hockney, David</li>
        <li>02. Matisse, Henri</li>
        <li>01. Picasso, Pablo</li>
    </ol>
</section>
```

Artists

- Picasso, Pablo
- Matisse, Henri
- Hockney, David

---

What I am having trouble with is figuring out how to (use jQuery to) toggle 'reversed' to the `<ol>` as it's not a `.class` or `.id`...

As I only have basic understanding of jQuery, and honestly wouldn't know where to start, I was hoping to ask around here if this is even possible, and if so, how best to approach this?

---

This all I've got so far, am I on the right track?

```
$('section span').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('ol').toggle().append("reversed");
});
```

---

```js
$('section span').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('ol').toggle().append("reversed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <h1>artists <span>sort</span></h1>
    <ol>
        <li>Hockney, David</li>
        <li>Matisse, Henri</li>
        <li>Picasso, Pablo</li>
    </ol>
</section>
```

Comment: `$(this).closest('ol').attr('reversed', true)` to add the attribute, `$(this).closest('ol').removeAttr('reversed')` to remove it

Comment: Please create a working example of your problem. You can use jsfiddle or stack code editor itself. (click on edit question and you will see it)

Comment: @Emanuel ah! so 'reversed' is an 'attribute' I did not know that!

Comment: @ServingQuarantineperiod Thanks for the tip! Let me try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a working example, let me know in case HTML structure is change.

```js
$('section span').on('click', function(e) {
   var OlObj = $(this).parent('h1').next('ol');
   OlObj.append( OlObj.find('li').get().reverse());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <h1>artists <span>sort</span></h1>
    <ol>
        <li>Hockney, David</li>
        <li>Matisse, Henri</li>
        <li>Picasso, Pablo</li>
    </ol>
</section>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use the sort span in the `<h1>` in the above html?

Comment: Brilliant. So you get the parent `<h1>` first, and only *then* the next `<ol>`that makes send.

Comment: @Jordy  yes, did a bit modification as well. You can check that as well.